# How to generate 1024 files in write mode in C programming

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    FILE *fp[1024];
    char FILENAME[1024];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1024;i++){
        sprintf(FILENAME,"file%d.txt",i);
        fp[i]=fopen(FILENAME,"w");
        if(fp[i]==NULL){
           printf("file %d cannot be opened\n",i);
           exit(0);
       }
    }
}
```

In the above program I tried to create 1024 files but actually I could only create 508 files — running on Windows. Please help in resolving the issue.

Comment: On which operating system? With what settings?

Comment: Your OS can only support a limited number of open files, so please check up on what that is.

Comment: I have done programming in windows os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close each file after you create it. You are likely running into the limit on the maximum number of files you can have open per process (I am guessing that for you it will be 512). On linux/unix/BSD you can find out what the limit is with 'ulimit -l'

More info here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's what you meant, but this code generates 1024 files:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    char filename[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        sprintf(filename, "file%d.txt", i);
        fp = fopen(filename, "w");
        if (!fp) {
            printf("Could not open %s", filename);
            return -1;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,I missed to close each file

Answer (score 0):

The [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) function can fail. You need to check that case, and details are operating system specific (i.e. on failure `fopen` gives `NULL` according to the C standard [n1570](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html) §7.21.5.3, but the failure reason is generally related to `errno`, but might not be).

On Linux, `fopen` fails notably when the underlying [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) fails (and in some other cases). And `open` would fail with `EMFILE` when a per-process file descriptor limit is reached (see also [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html)...). Try at the very least:

```
snprintf(FILENAME, sizeof(FILENAME), "file%d.txt",i)
fp[i]=fopen(FILENAME,"w");
if(fp[i]==NULL){
       printf("file %d cannot be opened - %s\n",i, strerror(errno));
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

On Windows, dive into the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx) for equivalent details.

<sup>(from my incomplete understanding, on Windows `fopen` failure reasons also go into `errno`, but the C11 standard don't guarantee such a relationship)</sup>

As [atmostmediocre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49601715/841108) shows, you'll better limit the number of `fopen`-ed `FILE*` handles, notably by `fclose`-ing them quickly.

**`FILE*` handles are** somehow **expensive resources** in general. On some systems, you might be limited to a few dozens of them (but on others, you might be able to successfully `fopen` several thousands files). With some operating systems you could configure that limit (e.g. [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_NOFILE` for [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) limit on Linux).

<sup>(How to change that limit is a different question, and it is operating system and perhaps computer specific)</sup>

As a rule of thumb, you want to limit the number of active `fopen`-ed `FILE*` handles. Having a thousands of them may be unreasonable (but details are OS and computer specific). In general you should call [fclose](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose) as soon as you are done with processing a `FILE*`.

<sup>(In your case you might loop a few thousands times in `fopen`-ing, `fwrite`-ing and `fprintf`-ing your file, then `fclose`-ing it; so you could have only one active `FILE*` handle - inside your loop)</sup>

Comment: I am upvoting Basile - you are on the right track and reminded me that Pullaro should have checked errno. You would have noticed that it was returning EMFILE which is defined as Too many open files (24) (here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) . When debugging it is important to check all of the information being given to you, or ask is there anything else you are missing.